# Regular expression to match specific number in query string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression that matches if a parameter in a query string contains a specific number in a comma separated array.

To illustrate by example let's I have query strings that looks like this:

```
str1 = "var1=ads12fafff&var2=10,1,5,200&var3=asdfvvv" # should not match
str2 = "var1=adsfsadff&var2=12,15&var3=dasfdsfsadf" # should match
str3 = "var1=dsafasdf&var2=50,12,1,20&var3=asdffae" # should match
```

…and now I want to match which strings contain the number **12** in **var2** - i e **str2** and **str3**.

Anyone got an idea how that might look?

Comment: what language is this in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
var2=(?:\d+,)*12(?:,|&|$)
```

Using it against each line, if there is a match, then do something.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/gY5pC6/3)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It almost works I think - only catch is that it also seems to match numbers that contain 12, like 120 or 4120.

Comment: @ErikÖstling It also matches 12 inside var3=. what language is this in?

Comment: @gymbrall It's for Ruby.

Comment: @ErikÖstling. Sorry for that.. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var2=[\d,]*12[,\d]*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qUdRZYnXXLa5k0pq)

It matches...

- *`str2`:*  `var1=adsfsadff&var2=12,15&var3=dasfdsfsadf`
- *`str3`:*  `var1=dsafasdf&var2=50,12,1,20&var3=asdffae`

...and does not match:

- *`str1`:*  `var1=ads12fafff&var2=10,1,5,200&var3=asdfvvv`
- *`str3` variation:*  `var1=50,12,1,20&var2=dsafasdf&var3=asdffae`